# Getting value from Firebase if another value in another collection is true

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I currently have a users collection in my Firebase real-time database that contains all my users and a collection that contains the name of books and the ratings(number of thumbs up and down). I am trying to make a application that will display book titles constantly(or the ones that are in my db) so that people can rate them, however I need to be able to check if a user has already viewed this book title or not(this is the part i need help with). Can someone help me with pulling the data from Firebase and comparing it to see if the user has viewed this book title or not. This is what my db setup looks like[image]

Also if someone has a better way of doing this please explain!!!

Comment: could you elaborate more on what exactly do you want to retrieve

Answer (score 0):

First, change `books_viewed` into an array. Read [this](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for arrays in Firebase Realtime Database

Now that it's an array, you can get that as a `ArrayList<String>` in your app.

```
public class User {
    public ArrayList<String> booksViewed;
    ... // Other variables
}
```

Then just use the `contains` function to check if the book you need to find is in that list

```
DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child("<UserID>")

userRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
        String bookTitleYouAreChecking = "Twilight"    
        if (user.booksViewed.contains(bookTitleYouAreChecking)) {
            // User has viewed
        } else { 
            // User has not viewed
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        // ...
    }
})
```

Comment: I would strongly disagree with the idea to change `books_viewed` into an array. Since there is no specific reason why these books should be ordered, it is more convenient to use a HashMap. This will also be more convenient if a single book must be accessed directly without iterating over all the books. (See [this article](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html) for more informations)

Comment: That is actually the link I've also posted above

Comment: Oops sorry about that. But then, I don't see any valid reason to choose to use Arrays, because none of the "Good Use Cases for Storing Data in Arrays" fits into this use case, to my sense

Comment: lets say i wanted to display these books in a different order for every different user, would that change how i would take the data from the db?

Comment: Nope, you won't have to change it

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following method that checks if a user had viewed a book or not:

```
private void checkBookTitle(String bookTitle) {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("Users").child(uid).child("books_viewed");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                    if (entry.getValue().equals(bookTitle)) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User has viewed this book");
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "User has not viewed this book");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
}
```

Comment: what does the ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent() at the bottom do?

Comment: In order to display those objects, you need first to attach a listener on that particular reference, right?